# authentication and authorization with Loopback

Tags: jquery, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, google-api-nodejs-client

we are developing a small application with loopback and NodeJs. it means we Created the Rest API in loopback . now we need to add authentication and authorization functionality .

we are using Postman for Testing the Rest APIs. please tell us how can we implement this task in our APP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) or [OAuth 2](http://www.seedbox.com/en/blog/2015/06/05/oauth-2-vs-json-web-tokens-comment-securiser-un-api/)

[image]

There are some npm packages available, Implement the suitable package for your application.

1. [loopback-auth0-jwt](https://github.com/jouke/loopback-auth0-jwt)
2. [loopback-jwt](https://github.com/whoGloo/loopback-jwt)
3. [loopback-component-oauth2](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-oauth2)

Comment: is there diff between oAuth2 and JWT !!

Comment: please suggest  us , how can we implement this in our APP.

Comment: Please look out the difference and choose the best one for your application - http://www.seedbox.com/en/blog/2015/06/05/oauth-2-vs-json-web-tokens-comment-securiser-un-api/

Comment: thanks , if you suggest us  some steps to do than it will better for us .

Comment: Hi @karthick , I want to develop a Client Server with loopback (as per your given Suggestion) , But I need your help for start development .  give me a short idea for development .